# Is it possible to install lein from a clone of the leiningen repository on the stable branch?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, dotfiles

I'm trying to setup the leiningen repo in my dotfiles, which involves adding a specific verison of the repo to my dotfiles repo and then using a script to link the `/bin/lein` script that one would normally download and run in order to install leiningen, or at least this is how I thought it would work.

What's actually happening is that when I do this setup and then run `lein`, I get the following message:

```
Leiningen is missing its dependencies.
Please run "lein bootstrap" in the leiningen-core/ directory
with a stable release of Leiningen. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
```

I don't understand why I'd be getting this message since I am in fact linking a version of `lein` from a repo checked out on the `stable` branch.

Does anyone what might be going on here and how I could achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `bin/lein` from inside of a source checkout of the repository, it assumes you are developing leiningen, in which case you must perform additional bootstrapping actions. If you want to just use lein without developing it, you don't need a whole repository, just the `bin/lein` script from stable. Cloning the repository and trying to use `bin/lein` in-place without any bootstrapping is not a supported usage mode.

If for some reason you want the full clone but don't want to build it yourself, you must *copy* the `bin/lein` script elsewhere, not link to it.

Comment: I linked the `bin/lein` script to `~/bin`. Shouldn't this have run it outside the repo when called from the environment path?